# A lot of Mediaplayers shrink to one Mediaplayer? How? Soundboard

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm a Java/Android Studio beginner and I'm writing a Soundboard.

My Soundboard has about 10-15 Buttons per Page and this is my following Problem

I'm declaring a lot of Mediaplayers

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 MediaPlayer X1;
 MediaPlayer X2;
 MediaPlayer X3;
 MediaPlayer X4;
 MediaPlayer X5;
 MediaPlayer X6;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    X1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.x1);
    X2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.x2);
    X3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.x3);
    X4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.x4);
    X5 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.x5);
    X6 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.6);
```

And in my XML files I'm working like this for each Button

```xml
<Button
        android:text="X1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:onClick="X1"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:background="android:attr/colorEdgeEffect"
        android:forceHasOverlappingRendering="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|italic"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="317dp" />
```

Now My Problems is it is a lot of work for each Mediaplayer and with a lot of Mediaplayers the App is crashing/doing problems.

How can I sum up all Buttons to one MediaPlayer?

It is just an example code how I am working could somebody change this code for me? 
In some Threads I read "oncompletionlistener" but I never worked with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stackoverflow would not let me answer, but I'll try again:

- You can reuse one reference to media player, no need to define serveral ones.
- You should determine which raw audio to play inside your onClick handler (i.e. the method called when button is clicked, you have the view as parameter here) based on button id (or something like that), i.e. call create on the same reference using another raw audio id.

Something like:

```
android:onClick="playFile"
```

And then you have

```
public void playFile(View view){
       switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
      // play audio file 1
      break;
    case R.id.button2:
      // play audio file 2
      break;
     //....
  }
 }
```